# How to do Incremental loading without comparing with whole data?

Tags: apache-spark, hive, azure-data-factory, azure-databricks

I was trying to do incremental load from my on-prem data lake to azure data lake gen2.

```
select 
ac_id,mbr_id ,act_id ,actdttm,
cretm ,rsltyid,hsid,cdag,cdcts  
from df2_hs2_lakeprd_ACTV_table where cdcts > last modified date
```

I am very less records updating or adding daily. My Source table is very large. When I run above query ADF copy activity is taking so much of time to load. I think The filer condition is begin checked with all records in the source table so, it is taking time.

Is there any way I can query or anything and make it will directly load updated records from the
source. And also my source table is partitioned by date can partitioned column will help in load fast.

Comment: yes, partitioned column will help in load fast. So, add that partition column(s) in where clause.

Comment: what is  format of the source table?

Comment: It is an external table with ROW FORMAT SERDE:  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.serde.ParquetHiveSerDe'

Answer (score 0):

Why not

1. Have the incremental files land into 2 folders. A. `incremental_yyyy_mm_dd_hh_min_seconds` B. `Datalake`
2. Read from the `incremental` folder always this way you may end up reading only delta or the excess records you read will be very low. Once the incremental folder is read maintain status that the folder is read.

So the `datalake` folder will always have the full snapshot.

Comment: Please refrain from using txtspk like "u" and "ur". Stack Overflow is not a chatroom.